# MongoDB ObjectID and date extraction

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm extracting the creation date from the MongoDB ObjectID and output this in Jade template engine. Everything works well, but I would like to "limit" the output a bit...

This is the output in my views: 
*Fri Sep 13 2013 09:40:40 GMT+0200 (Västeuropa, sommartid)*

But I would like something shorter, like this instead: 
*Fri Sep 13 2013*

Can someone please tell me how to do this.

Comment: How are you currently outputting the data using Jade? (I assume you want to limit the output from Jade, not MongoDB?)

Comment: Using a loop. each client in docs
"docs" is where the data is saved... 

in this loop i have: #{client._id.getTimestamp()}

Comment: Im thinking about a simple slice... just keep the first 15 letters and crop the rest. But there might be a better way to do it =)

Comment: I've had a lot of luck using momentjs.com for my date formatting and manipulation, both server and/or client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client._id.getTimestamp()` returns a `Date` Object.

So you'll need to format the date.

Here is how you can do it with `dateformat` module:

```
var dateformat = require('dateformat'); // npm install dateformat
// ...
var date = client._id.getTimestamp(),
    dateString = dateFormat(date, "ddd mmm dd yyyy"); // pass it to your jade template
```